# Is it possible to recover files from a linux scp that combined the files?

Tags: linux, command-line, data-recovery, scp, file-recovery

I accidentally typed this command when getting files from a server:

```
scp username@host:/data/* *
```

Which copied all the files from the directory on the server to a file * on my machine. Is it possible to recover those files?

Comment: Did the files get deleted on the server?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Unfortunately, I no longer have access to the server.

Comment: How do you know it combined the files? I mean, are there visible strings in *? Did it concatenate the binary versions of the server files or make some kind of "meta-file" like how dd can write to an image? Are the server files well-known file formats that you can use a tool like foremost against?

Comment: It didn't combine them; it copied each source file one at a time, so it copied file1, then it copied file2 replacing the copy of file1, then it copied file3 replacing the copy of file2 etc, leaving a copy of only the last file.

Comment: Sounds like an answer, @dave. (Though I did not test if it's true.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - Unfortunately I did the same thing. In my situation I did not not have a backup of the files. Did you ever recover them from your situation? Are they completely gone?